# javascript $.post returning correct result but cant catch all characters in returned string

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, .post

I am using $.post to write get a result from a database.

My syntax is:

```
     $.post('addbundle_summary', {id:id},function(resultsummary) { 
  alert(resultsummary[0]);
     })
```

I am using codeigniter and in my model I am returning the result as below. note that my sql always returns a single result so $stackid is always a single number:

```
return $stackid;
```

my controller send this back  to the function with:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

in developer tools, you can see the result from the function as per below image
[image]

even though the result is 23, my alert is showinf me 2. if the result was 573 it would alert 5.

How can I get this to return the entire result number and not just the first letter of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert(resultsummary[0])` is returning `resultsummary` string at index 0, which is `2`. use `alert(resultsummary)` instead.

```
$.post('addbundle_summary', {id:id},function(resultsummary) { 
  alert(resultsummary);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Convert your json data into string before alert

```
 $.post('addbundle_summary', {id:id},function(resultsummary) { 
  alert(JSON.stringify(resultsummary));
 })
```